# Button is not showing on View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I have a View in my activity where it contains one image, a text and a button...
[image]

So as you can see my button is showing there but its not visible...
It is going behind, I have tried to test it by marginTop attribute and if I move it down from the view then its visible...

I don't know how to do this but with the TextView when I use background then it changes the background color & works fine..
But I want to use Button instead of TextView

How can I do this or what I will have to do to bring the button front?

Below is my xml file code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Dashboard">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dashboard_layout"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:transitionName="bg_anim"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     />
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <!--This is the button-->
<!--Removed            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tv_welcome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:elevation="6dp"
               android:text="Hello,"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
    -->
<--added newly-->
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/tv_welcome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:text="Hello,"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="#B2FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:transitionName="user_anim"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_welcome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_display_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    
    
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:transitionName="profile_anim"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
    
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_undraw_male_avatar" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Your Dashboard"
                android:textColor="#ff1122"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

After changing some code...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `RelativeLayout` as parent and adding `constraints` to `Button` which only works when the parent is `ConstraintLayout`, to achieve same in `RelativeLayout` try `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` and `android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"` as in

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/tv_welcome"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
     android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
     android:elevation="6dp"
     android:text="Hello,"
     android:textColor="#fff"
     android:textSize="35sp"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Also remove elevation on `View` as it is just setting background

```
 <View
     android:id="@+id/view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="250dp"
     android:background="@drawable/dashboard_layout"
     android:transitionName="bg_anim"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: Tried above but still button is not visible or it is going behind...

Comment: Can you post new screenshot with above code, I can help if see what's happening

Comment: Yes. See I have updated your code and posted the current output...

Comment: I have updated answer, remove elevation on view it will definitely work, as view is used to only to set background, if you want view to be elevated then elevate the parent layout all together instead of view

Comment: Yes it is working I removed the elevation attribute...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_gradient_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_corner"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/save_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/user_name_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:ems="50"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Laxman Marothiya"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_subTitle_font_size_eighteen"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gender_info_textv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name_info"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ems="6"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_subTitle_font_size_eighteen" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_info_textv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gender_info_textv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ems="40"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Emaol@gmail.com"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size_fifteen" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bio_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email_info_textv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="200"
            android:text="Here is my bio can you see it actually this is very interesting here "
            android:textColor="@color/appBlackColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size_fifteen" />


    </RelativeLayout>


   


</RelativeLayout>
```